# Data in the form of table overflows the div in IE 8 and table disrupts

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer-8

I have a table created using div's and different classes applied to each of them. When the data in any of the column exceeds a line, the table structure gets distorted and everything gets messed up.

Chrome and Firefox automatically extends the row height to accomodate the data. Problem is only with Internet Explorer 8.

I am attaching the code below. Please provide your inputs.

Thanks

html goes here:

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="ListHead" id="list_div">
        <a class="ListItem col1" href="sort.do">
        <a class="ListItem col2" href="sort.do ">
        <a class="ListItem col3" href="sort.do">
        <a class="ListItem col4" href="sort.do">
        <a class="ListItem col5" href="sort.do">
    </div>
    <div class="ListRow0">
        <a class="ListItemRow col1" href="dosomething">
        <span class="ListItem col2">
        <span class="ListItem col3">
        <span class="ListItem col4">
        <span class="ListItem col5">
    </div>
    <div class="ListRow1">
        <a class="ListItemRow col1" href="dosomething">
        <span class="ListItem col2">
        <span class="ListItem col3">
        <span class="ListItem col4">
        <span class="ListItem col5">
    </div>
    <div class="ListRow0">
        <a class="ListItemRow col1" href="dosomething">
        <span class="ListItem col2">
        <span class="ListItem col3">
        <span class="ListItem col4">
        <span class="ListItem col5">
    </div>
    <div class="ListRow1">
        <a class="ListItemRow col1" href="dosomething">
        <span class="ListItem col2">
        <span class="ListItem col3">
        <span class="ListItem col4">
        <span class="ListItem col5">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
fieldset {
    margin: 0.5em 0 0 0;
    padding: 0.5em 0 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #bdc1c2;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #09072c;
    background-color: #f1f2f6;
    background-image: url(../image/BannerGifs/fieldset_grad.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

.ListHead {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    color: #09072c;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.ListRow0 {
    background-color: white;
    color: #09072c; 
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    padding: 5px;   
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.ListRow1 {
    background-color: #fbf9fb;
    color: #09072c; 
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    padding: 5px;   
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0.75em;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.ListItem {
    padding: 0 0.5em;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.col1 {
    width: 10%;
}
.col2 {
    width: 15%;
}
.col3 {
    width: 15%;
}
.col4 {
    width: 30%;
}
.col5 {
    width: 15%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replaced the table created using div by the simple table tag.

Was trying to retain existing code. After struggling for quite a while decided to replace all such tables for tabular data with the  code.

All issues solved.